# Show only "Pages" - not posts - on search page

Tags: search

When I have this URL:

http://localhost/website/?post_type=**post**&s=lorem

It shows me only the posts which have the word "lorem". Now I want to this with *pages*:

http://localhost/website/?post_type=**page**&s=lorem

I still get the posts. Any Idea? (With other custom post types like "portfolio" it works, too).

Answer (score 1):

Setting the post type at `pre_get_posts` can solve this. You can set it like below-

```
function the_dramatist_search_only_page($query) {

    if ($query->is_search && !is_admin() ) {
        $query->set('post_type',array('page'));
    }

    return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts','the_dramatist_search_only_page');
```

Hope it helps.